# What is the correct way to debounce method in React + Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to debounce AJAX requests in Filter component. The problem is that I also want to show loader when the user starts typing, but this causes the component to rerender and `handleChange` method redeclares so that debounce doesn't work as I expected. What is the correct way to handle this?

```
const QuestionsPage: React.FunctionComponent<T.IQuestionsPageProps> = (props) => {
    const debouncedFilter = debounce(props.fetchFilteredQuestions, 500);

    const handleChange = (values: any) => {
        props.setFetching(true);
        debouncedFilter(values);
    };

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <QuestionsSearchForm
                className={s.form}
                handleChange={handleChange}
            />
            {
                props.isFetching && <p>FETCHING</p>
            }
            { ... mapping list ... }
        </Wrapper>
    );
};
```